Function template overloading when called with reference type rejected by clang but accepted by gcc and msvc
I wrote the following program that has overloaded function templates but the program is rejected by clang and accepted by both gcc and msvc. Demo
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
template< class T > void f( T& t ){} ;
template< class T > void f( const T&& ) {};
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f<int&>(i); //clang:nope, gcc:ok, msvc:ok
} 

Clang says:
<source>:10:5: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
   10 |     f<int&>(i); //clang:nope, gcc:ok, msvc:ok
      |     ^~~~~~~
<source>:4:26: note: candidate function [with T = int &]
    4 | template< class T > void f( T& t ){} ;
      |                          ^
<source>:5:26: note: candidate function [with T = int &]
    5 | template< class T > void f( const T&& ) {};
      |        

I want to know which compiler is correct here according to the c++ standard.

Note that with an actual forwarding reference it does compile https://godbolt.org/z/P9nhbsMr4

@AlanBirtles Yes, I checked that.

Clang is correct, neither candidate is better than the other.
Both f<int&> candidates take a single int& argument, so conversion sequences can't be used to determine which is a better candidate for the call (they are identical). The tie-breaker here is which function template is more specialised.
This goes [over.match.best.general]p(2.5) → [temp.func.order]p4 → [temp.deduct.partial]. Here, references are removed and then cv-qualifiers are removed, however they are considered later in [temp.deduct.partial]p9:

If, for a given type, the types are identical after the transformations above and both P and A were reference types (before being replaced with the type referred to above):

if the type from the argument template was an lvalue reference and the type from the parameter template was not, the parameter type is not considered to be at least as specialized as the argument type; otherwise,
if the type from the argument template is more cv-qualified than the type from the parameter template (as described above), the parameter type is not considered to be at least as specialized as the argument type.


So when the argument template is #1 and the parameter template is #2, #2 is not at least as specialized as #1 (because A was an lvalue reference and P was not).
When the argument template is #2 and the parameter template is #1, #1 is not at least as specialized as #2 (because A was more cv-qualified).
.. Since neither is at least as specialized as the other, neither is more specialized than the other.
There are no more applicable tie-breakers, so neither is a better candidate for the call than the other, so it's ambiguous.
If you were to make either of the above conditions false (i.e., make #1 take a T&& so it's no longer an lvalue reference, make #2 take const T& so it's now also an lvalue reference or make #1 not less cv-qualified like const T& or volatile T&), then it would no longer be ambiguous.
E.g.:
template<typename T> void f(T&&);
template<typename T> void f(const T&&);  // f<int&>(i) calls this one

template<typename T> void g(T&);
template<typename T> void g(const T&);  // g<int&>(i) calls this one

template<typename T> void h(volatile T&);  // h<int&>(i) calls this one
template<typename T> void h(const T&&);


Yes, I reached the same conclusion and posted the same reasoning here just before this answer was posted here.

Same conclusion here. In brief, T& t and const T&& t just specify how the parameter will be passed. They don't select between different kinds of parameters, no variant is more specialized than the other, and the compiler can't (shouldn't) solve the ambiguity.

@Artyer You got the order wrong when you wrote "because P was an lvalue reference and A was not". It should be changed to "because A was an lvalue reference and P was not". Do the same for the other case also.

Richard Hodges answer here is really good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495592/c-templates-cant-deduce-reference-types-without-using

@user12002570 Fixed the P and A

@DiegoFerruchelli This is just an oddity when explicitly specifying template arguments. A similar thing happens for void f(auto*); void f(auto**); int main() { f<void>(nullptr); } calling the second since the template it comes from is more specialised. This seems like an unintentional side effect.

In your example, there is a more specialized form because T * and T ** (after the auto expansion) are actual data types. Then, the more specialized form is chosen (even when the other one may seem more appropriate). It's a different thing with T& t and const T&& t (the OP question) because these forms just specify parameter passing mechanisms (and, as you said, no one is more specialized than the other).

The program is ill-formed due to temp.deduct.partial#9 because temp.deduct.partial#9.1 make the second overload not to be atleast as specialized as the first and then temp.deduct.partial#9.2 make the first template not to be atleast as specialized as the second. So neither overloads are at least as specialized than the other and hence also neither of them more specialized.
Here is the reported gcc and msvc bug:
GCC accepts invalid call to overloaded function template when neither is at least as specialized as the other
MSVC accepts invalid call to overloaded function template when neither is at least as specialized as the other
